# java.lang.IllegalStateException: JsonDeserializer must be configured with property setters, or via configuration properties; not both

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-kafka

Getting exception when migrated spring boot version 2.4.2 to 2.6.8.

06:20:15,693 ERROR [stderr] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 98) ERROR SpringApplication Application run failed
common          | 06:20:15,693 ERROR [stderr] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 98)  org.springframework.context.ApplicationContextException: Failed to start bean 'org.springframework.kafka.config.internalKafkaListenerEndpointRegistry'; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: JsonDeserializer must be configured with property setters, or via configuration properties; not both
common          | 06:20:15,694 ERROR [stderr]....

Using: Spring boot 2.6.8
Spring cloud 2021.0.1

Answer (score 1):

The error message is quite clear; you must either configure the deserializer completely using `set...()` methods, or use consumer properties; you can't mix and match.

If you have called any `set...()` methods, the consumer configuration map must not contain any `spring.json.*` properties.

Comment: Thanks Gary for the reply. Yes I can see that we are calling addtrustedpackage which is setting setterCalled flag to true. Will check how configured flag is getting true value.